# Why foreach works while removing items from ListView and doesn't work from ListBox?

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, foreach

I've started learning C# and I'm a bit confused about the behavior that I discovered. I try to figure out, why in one case the code is working and in another not:

```
foreach (ListViewItem l in listView1.SelectedItems) l.Remove();
foreach (object l in listBox1.SelectedItems) listBox1.Items.Remove(l);
```

First one works fine and there is no error, but the second one throws exception with information that the collection was changed.

Could anyone explain it to me?

PS. In case of ListView I was debugging code and collection SelectedItems was changing, but even though it worked well.

Comment: I'm actually surprised it works in the first case. The key point: collection-like objects are not **required** to support continued enumeration after changes are made, but may optionally choose to do so

Comment: i'm also surprised and because of that i asked the question :)

Comment: Where's @JonSkeet when you need him ? :)

Comment: It's just a plain bug in the framework code.  You are dealing with two distinct collection classes.  The ListBox class uses ObjectCollection, the ListView class uses ListViewItemCollection.  Two Microsoft programmers that wrote them, the ListBox guy forgot to throw the exception.  Too late to fix it now, there's somebody out there that depends on the odd numbered items getting removed.  This goes back to .NET version 1.0, they got much more contentious about it since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I read the code inside .NET, more specifically `ListBox.cs` and `ListView.cs`, they have two different classes for keeping their `SelectedItems` collections.

`ListBox.cs` has `SelectedObjectCollection`, which has these members:

```cs
private ListBox owner;
private bool    stateDirty; 
private int     lastVersion; 
private int     count;
```

`ListView.cs` has `SelectedListViewItemCollection`, which has these members only:

```cs
private ListView owner;
private int lastAccessedIndex = -1;
```

So by looking at that, I guess I can deduce that `ListBox`'s collection is a proper enumerator that keeps track of any changes and the number of items that are in the list.
`ListView`, on the other hand, seems to not care about that at all, and only keep track of the current index of the enumerator and simply steps forward.

So `ListBox` throws the exception since it keeps track of modifications, `ListView` does not.

**EDIT**:
`ListBox.cs`'s `SelectecObjectCollection`'s GetEnumerator method looks like this:

```cs
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return InnerArray.GetEnumerator(SelectedObjectMask); 
}
```

And `ListView.cs`'s `SelectedListViewItemCollection`'s  GetEnumerator method looks like this:

```cs
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { 
    if (owner.VirtualMode) { 
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.ListViewCantAccessSelectedItemsCollectionWhenInVirtualMode));
    } 

    ListViewItem[] items = SelectedItemArray;
    if (items != null) {
        return items.GetEnumerator(); 
    }
    else { 
        return new ListViewItem[0].GetEnumerator(); 
    }
}
```

So it looks like `ListView` returns an enumerator of an array, which is constant, whilst `ListBox` returns an actual enumerator as a filter of its InnerArray of items.

I know this is not what you asked about; but it is always favorable to add all items to a temporary List before looping through it to remove things, since you can **never** know how the enumerators are implemented on the backend, nor how they might change in the future.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't what i asked about? :) i think last part and  source code of GetEnumerator of ListView is it.
I thought so, that enumerator keeps working this foreach, but i didn't know  how to get source code of ListView. I've tried F12, after select "ListView", but there were only declarations, not definitions. So tell me where did you find this code :)?

Comment: My last part was misunderstood, I guess. I meant that you didn't ask about what to do, just why it works. And I gave a little sidenote of how you should do it there.

And I get the source code by using ReSharper. It downloads the code when I control-click it.

Comment: Oh, yes, i didn't ask about what to do, but this sidenote seems usefull, so thanks for explanation and solution.

Comment: I consider it's worth pointing out that, given the implementation, ListView's enumerator can return elements removed from its source after it was created. I'll have to take that into account next time I use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (myListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    myListBox.Items.Remove(myListBox.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Comment: The question was about **Why** the exception in the 2nd case and not in the first, not **how** to remove an all the items.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a collection over which you are enumerating. That's why you are getting an exception in the second example.

The Remove method on the ListView item is designed to not throw an exception in this situation.

Comment: I assume MS just wrote that Remove method to be safe in this situation.