# Remove some items of ListView.SelectedItems using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, listview

Is there a simple solution to remove specific itemS from ListView.SelectedItems?

I've a ListView bound to an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` (MyClass has some attributes e.g. Name).

Something like:

```
mylistview.SelectedItems.Remove(FROM myClassItem IN mylistview.SelectedItems WHERE myClassItem.Name == "test");
```

Of course, it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to be that you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt#comment14709180_853551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in mylistview.SelectedItems
                               .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                               .Where(lvi => lvi.Name == "test")
    item.Remove();
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this might cause run time exception, as it modify the collection while it iterate over it.

Comment: @Tamir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379072/why-foreach-works-while-removing-items-from-listview-and-doesnt-work-from-listb